# Problem starting cluster on azure databricks with version 6.4 Extended Support (includes Apache Spark 2.4.5, Scala 2.11)

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

I have configured a cluster on azure databricks, which uses version: 6.4 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.5, Scala 2.11). This version is found to be deprecated.
This cluster is configured to run 2 scripts when it starts and everything is working correctly.

I need to configure the same cluster but in another azure environment, I created everything just like the other cluster that is working, but because this runtime version is deprecated, I configured it with the "new" available version 6.4 **Extended Support** (includes Apache Spark 2.4.5, Scala 2.11). With this Runtime change, I get an error starting the cluster when the init scripts are run.

[LOG INIT_SCRIPTS_FINISHED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Crmye.png)

The file "dbfs:/FileStore/tables/init_install.sh" is as follows:

```
apt update -y
apt-get install libav-tools libavcodec-extra -y --fix-missing
```

I researched about changes that have existed between these two runtime versions and found this page:
https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/6.4x.html

Get me some help figuring out what I need to change in this file to be compatible with this new runtime version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this issue is not related to runtime version . Since you are trying to create cluster in another azure environment respective init script location won't available . DBFS locations are in work space level . So respective same location will not be there in another azure environment . That’s reason this issue occurs. So that you can create init script file in expected azure environment and attach with that cluster through cluster UI .

How to create Init script :

```
dbutils.fs.put("/FileStore/tables/init_install.sh","""
apt update -y
apt-get install libav-tools libavcodec-extra -y --fix-missing""", True)
```

Update the respective location in cluster config :

[image]

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your response.
The file is in the new azure environment (another file is also in this same location and there is no error).

I tried to do a test that was to change the old environment, where the runtime version is deprecated, I changed this version to the "new" one and that same cluster stopped starting and the same error appears that appears in the new environment.

Comment: can you please try to create cluster without init script first to narrow down the issue whether related to init script or not. If you are able to create cluster without init script means issue related init script else run time version issue .

Comment: Yes, I've done this test too.
I created a cluster without the initial script and the cluster starts with no problems.

Comment: In the same environment that was working with version 6.4 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.5, Scala 2.11) I just changed to the "new" version 6.4 Extended Support (includes Apache Spark 2.4.5, Scala 2.11) and the cluster stopped starting.

Comment: am suspecting issue with 'apt update -y' in init script . what are you trying to execute with this command ?

Comment: With tihis command I am trying to update my package list.

Comment: But to avoid the problem, I deleted this command from the script, but the error is the same.
"status": "FAILED_EXECUTION",
"execution_duration_seconds": 1,
"error_message": "Script exit status is non-zero"

Comment: can you try with following commands alone ?
sudo apt-get install libav-tools libavcodec-extra-56
sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: So , we can conclude this issue is not related to Run time version and that should be  related to init script .

Comment: Please evaluate , why you are required ? libavcodec . are you processing any video and audio data. Libavcodec is a free and open-source library of codecs for encoding and decoding video and audio data.

Comment: any luck ? Did you find anything on libavcodec

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay in responding.
I tried doing it in separate runs, for example just the command "apt-get install libav-tools", but the error in the init script is the same.